# How to combine a basic sumo scenario with omnet++ network?

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I am using the virtual machine instant-veins-4-7-1-i1.ova on VirtualBox.

I have created a sumo scenario with 2 vehicles (`my_nodes.nod.xml`, `my_edge.edg.xml`, `my_type.type.xml`, `my_net.net.xml`, `my_net.rou.xml`, `my_config_file.sumocfg` ).
Launching the sumo-gui command from the terminal and selecting `my_config_file.sumocfg` file, I can run the scenario simulation.

I have followed the Tictoc tutorial on Omnet++ site and if I run it on Omnet++ IDE, it will work fine.

In the Omnet++ IDE, I am able to run correctly the Veins Erlangen example.

Now, I would like to integrate my sumo scenario and the Tictoc network to realize a simulation similar to the Veins Erlangen example.
Which are the steps that I should follow?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straightforward answer would be to modify [the Veins 4.7.1 tutorial simulation's network](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.7.1/examples/veins/RSUExampleScenario.ned) by adding a `Tic` node and a `Toc` node. I am guessing, though, that this is not what you had in mind. You probably want to change the Veins tutorial simulation to use your `my_config_file.sumocfg` instead of [its own `erlangen.sumo.cfg` file](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.7.1/examples/veins/erlangen.sumo.cfg).

The file that is [configured as the road traffic simulation in omnetpp.ini](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.7.1/examples/veins/omnetpp.ini#L49) is called [`erlangen.launchd.xml`](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.7.1/examples/veins/erlangen.launchd.xml). By changing this file (or configuring the simulation to use another one) you can change which SUMO scenario is simulated when you run the Veins example.